# Visual Studio Code git/source control gutter stopped showing

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Working with VS Code, the explorer git status [gutter indicators](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators) stopped showing for one of my repositories.

- I tried rebooting VS Code, My PC
- I tried removing the index file and
  git reset

Those didn't resolve the issue.

(Git changes are still tracked in the Source Control Manager panel)

Comment: historical note: there was a specific, rather high-visibility bug in VS Code 1.76.1 that broke SCM diff decorations: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75715788/11107541

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apparently another common reason for this is that you are accessing your git repo through a symlink. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60010#issuecomment-433424527

This was the case for me and redirecting vscode to open the folder via the full path fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

This started happening to me when opening subdirectories from a monorepo.

I had to to set the "Open Repository In Parent Folders" setting to "always" to make it work.

[image]

Or in json:

```
"git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "always"
```

Not sure when this option has appeared or default changed because the git gutter used to work without this setting.

Comment: Thank you, I ran into this as well! Setting this solved the issue for me. I guess there was a behavior change in some recent version of VS Code?

Comment: Yes, [this is a recent addition (January 2023)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_git-repositories-in-parent-folders)

Comment: Ty! This is exactly what happened to me.

Answer (score 6):

It took me a long while to figure this one out. My changes were still being seen by VSCode and Gitlens, but they were not being tracked in the gutters... for SOME files. Uninstalling VSCode and re-installing would allow tracking for a bit, but even with all extensions off, it would eventually stop tracking in the gutter.

My solution:

I had renamed a few folders by changing the case. Git was not set to track case-sensitive, my Mac was viewing them as the same file, and VSCode was just being VSCode... Going back and renaming the files through Git ended up fixing the issue:

```
git mv navigation tmp
git mv tmp Navigation
```

successfully updated it. If it isn't working, I also had to updated git global (temporarily) and pushed with:

```
git config --global core.ignoreCase false
```

Comment: This saved my day! I have a nx monorepo and istg Idk since when the gutter indicators were gone for some of the capitalized files. This is so random and hard to figure out. Idk how you figure this out, but kudos and many thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me has been to delete my folder (after saving/pushing it on the remote) and cloning the repo again.

Comment: For me restarting the computer did the trick. Interestingly enough the git gutter wouldn't show in one project but did show in other projects. That seems specifically weird. In any case: After the restart it works in all projects again.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but strangely enough, none of the above solutions worked for me.

Comment: This solution works for me. While restarting the PC does not work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case gutters disappeared from `flutter` repository. I think it happened after I upgraded flutter to 3.7.7.

I created a simple repository with one `.txt` file and ensured that gutters not working there as well.

At the same time I observed that gutters worked normally in `c++` repo.

So I tried to rename one `.dart` file in `flutter` repo to `.cpp`. Then I renamed it back to `.dart` and gutters appeared again.

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the gutter doesn't show if the folder path contains a `.`, like `/home/user.focus/folder`

Change the path to one without `.` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue and found out that deleting my workspace file and then creating it anew has resolved the problem.

I have found out this was only happening in one workspace and not the others. Something in my workspace file must have gotten messed up somehow. When I opened another workspace, the gutter icon highlighting worked fine, but then when I went back to the problematic workspace it was still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i recently installed an extension for solidity, and this extension made the problem i uninstalled, restarted vscode and everything went back to normal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).